# Text Animate - Scrolling

Tags: vb.net

Currently I'm using this vb.net code, that I found online, below to scoll text up a form. Is there a way to have muliple text scrolling at the same time? So for my array I'd have Item2 right below Item1 and so on depending on how many items were in the array? I want each new item to be scrolled right below the next one.

```
 Option Strict Off  'Strict has to be off for the font
Public Class Form1

   Dim sItems() As String = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"}

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      For index As Integer = 0 To sItems.Length - 1
         animateText(sItems(index), Button1.Location.Y - 50, Button1.Location.Y - 50, Button1.Location.X)
      Next
   End Sub
   Dim label As New Label
   Dim maxHeight As Integer
   Dim colour As Integer = 255
   Public Sub animateText(ByVal text As String, ByVal lowerBounds As Integer, ByVal upperBounds As Integer, ByVal xPos As Integer)
         maxHeight = upperBounds
         label.Text = text
         label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
         label.Location = New Point(xPos, lowerBounds)
         label.Font = New Font(Font.Bold, 20)
         label.AutoSize = True
         Me.Controls.Add(label)
      Timer1.Enabled = True
   End Sub
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
      label.Location = New Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y - 20)  'here's where you set the speed
      If label.Location.Y = maxHeight Then
         Timer1.Enabled = False
         Me.Controls.Remove(label)
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a **List** of Labels, instead of using just one.

Try this out instead:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private maxHeight As Integer
    Private labels As New List(Of Label)
    Private sItems() As String = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each lbl As Label In labels
            Me.Controls.Remove(lbl)
        Next
        labels.Clear()

        maxHeight = Button1.Bounds.Bottom
        For index As Integer = 0 To sItems.Length - 1
            animateText(sItems(index), Button1.Location.X)
        Next
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub animateText(ByVal text As String, ByVal xPos As Integer)
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Text = text
        lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        lbl.Font = New Font(Font.Bold, 20)
        lbl.AutoSize = True
        lbl.Location = New Point(xPos, If(labels.Count = 0, Button1.Bounds.Bottom, labels(labels.Count - 1).Bounds.Bottom))
        labels.Add(lbl)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim lbl As Label
        For i As Integer = labels.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            lbl = labels(i)
            lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, lbl.Location.Y - 20)
            If lbl.Bounds.Top <= maxHeight Then
                labels.RemoveAt(i)
                Me.Controls.Remove(lbl)
            End If
        Next
        If labels.Count = 0 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I like this method. My only question is what if I just want to add another new item below the current one when the button is clicked? I don't want them all on the screen at the same time. I click the button and it'll insert while the other one is still scrolling. Eventually I'm want to interface this so that items will get added on the fly.

Comment: Just call animateText() with your values and it will get added!  The only change you might need is if you want it to always appear at the bottom and not directly below the currently scrolling item...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should start by showing two lines. As the first line scrolls off the screen, add the next line below and remove the line that is no-longer visible.

Since you will have 2 lines, your height calculations will have to be 1/2 of the current values.

Within your timer loop, instead of ending the loop, you will have to detect the newline condition or end condition.  Current line should be a modular var.  Remove the loop from your button_click event (loop within the timer instead).

Change the timer loop code like this:

```
private index as integer '=0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  label.Location = New Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y - 20)  'here's where you set the speed
  If label.Location.Y = (maxHeight / 2) Then
     If index < 3 Then 'next line
        Label.Text = sItems(index) & vbCrLf & sItems(index+1)
     Else 'last line
        Label.Text = sItems(index)
     End If 
     'reset the top
     label.Location = New Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y + (maxHeight/2))

     index += 1
  ElsIf label.Location.Y >= maxHeight Then
     Timer1.Enabled = False
     Me.Controls.Remove(label)
  End If
End Sub
```

Without seeing your entire form definition (ie. maxHeight = ?) I'm not sure that this code is exact, but I'm pretty sure you can see the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still can only see Item1 scroll. I never seen any other items. Is this because of my height? I've tried different height values.